# How can I authenticate the user within Json controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, yui

I have a .NET MVC controller action that returns a JsonResult to a YUI AsyncRequest callback. All is working fine with the AsyncRequest call and the "Content" model data is successfully updated. How can I now assure that the user is logged before the AsyncRequest is made?

Normally I would use the [Authorize] attribute which returns an error back to my YUI AsyncRequest since it is expecting a Json result.

I've also tried checking "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" wihtin the Action but still no love.. The RedirectToRoute seems to do nothing.

I have been able to send a Json result back to JS that indicated the user needs to login, but I'd rather have it redirect the user to the LogOn view.

Here is the Controller action:

```
[JsonFilter(Param="content"), JsonDataType=typeof(Content)]
public ActionResult SaveJson(Content content) 
{

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        RedirectToRoute(new { Action="LogOn", Controller="Account"});


    contentRepository.Update(content);
    return Json(new {Result = "sucess"});

}
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
[JsonFilter(Param="content"), JsonDataType=typeof(Content)]
public ActionResult SaveJson(Content content) 
{

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
        return Json(new {Result = "unauthenticated" , Url = urlHelper.Action("LogOn", "Account")});
    }

    contentRepository.Update(content);
    return Json(new {Result = "sucess"});
}
```

You will use `urlHelper.Action("LogOn", "Account")` part of result to change location to login page (`window.location.href = ...`).

**Additional note:** You can move `urlHelper.Action("LogOn", "Account")` to your view, as a part of your callback function.

Comment: Thanks.. I started to think about using window.location in my JS, and I like your idea of passing the url back to it,

Comment: @Skelly: Remember that you don't have to pass it, you can already have it during view generation and that is propably more preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the semantically correct thing to do is return an HTTP response with a 401 (Unauthorized) status code and let the js decide how to respond.  I'm not familiar with YUI, but in jQuery you can setup an error callback function like so...

```
function BasicJSONPost(urlToPost, dataToSend, onSuccess) {
$.ajax({
    url: urlToPost,
    data: dataToSend,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        HandleAjaxError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
}

function HandleAjaxError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 401) {
        window.location.href = '/account/login';
    }
}
```